# How to display field "VAT Number" during registration on frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, registration, customer-registration, taxvat

How to display field "VAT Number" (required)  during registration.

This field is visible when editing the user from the administration panel. Only how to display them during registration?
[image]

I found  code in:

> app/design/frontend/{YOUR_PACKAGE}/{YOUR_THEME}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

This file contains fields that are displayed during registration:

```
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
        <div class="field company">
            <label for="company" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Company') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label for="telephone" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>

        <div class="field street required">
            <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_streetValidationClass ?>">
                <div class="nested">
                    <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                    <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                        <div class="field additional">
                            <label class="label" for="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i ?>">
                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Address') ?></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address %1', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_streetValidationClass ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field required">
            <label for="city" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field region required">
            <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                    <option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Please select a region, state or province.') ?></option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field zip required">
            <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field country required">
            <label for="country" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php echo $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes');?>
        <?php if ($addressAttributes): ?>
            <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
            <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]');?>
            <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address');?>
            <?php echo $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml()?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
    </fieldset>
```

I also found this code  in this file:

```
<?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
    <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
    <<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use that field at customer registration, you need to enable all the other address fields and then add a addtional field for "vat_id" to /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml.

Then you need to add validation if you want the field to be required.

In the phtml file there is `<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>` change this to `<?php if (true): ?>` to show the address fields.

Then add a new field:

```
<div class="field vat_id required">
            <label for="vat_id" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('VAT Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="vat_id" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getVatId()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('VAT Number')) ?>" id="vat_id" class="input-text required <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('vat_id')) ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Of course you should use an own template file (in your theme or module) for this, instead of the core file.

Another possibility is https://www.geissweb.de/eu-vat-enhanced-for-magento-2.html which has a config option to show the address fields and the VAT number field at customer registration. You can also add validation to the field with the module, its options are:

- Optional
- Optional, but require a valid VAT number when filled
- Require a valid VAT number, validated through the validation service

Answer (score 0):

1. In the admin, navigate to:

   - *Stores > Settings > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options*
2. Set the following configuration:

   - **Show Tax/Vat Number:** Required
3. Clear cache
4. On frontend, navigate to customer registration page

[image: Customer Registration Page - Tax/Vat Number Field Required]